# timeline_aggregated empty for a user that get followed

Tags: getstream-io

Basically I have this model:

```
# models.py
class Follow(Activity, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='friends')
    target = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='followers')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'target', )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} follows {1}'.format(self.user, self.target)

    @property
    def extra_activity_data(self):
        return {'username': self.user.username}

    @classmethod
    def activity_related_models(cls):
        return ['user', 'target']

    @property
    def activity_notify(self):
        if not settings.STREAM_DISABLE_MODEL_TRACKING:
            # Another example would be following a user. You would commonly want to notify the user which is being
            # followed.
            return [feed_manager.get_notification_feed(self.target_id)]


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Follow)
def unfollow_user_feed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not settings.STREAM_DISABLE_MODEL_TRACKING:
        feed_manager.unfollow_user(instance.user_id, instance.target_id)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Follow)
def follow_user_feed(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and not settings.STREAM_DISABLE_MODEL_TRACKING:
        feed_manager.follow_user(instance.user_id, instance.target_id)
```

and a simple workflow can be

```
<load gab and freddy user instances>
Follow.objects.create(user=gab, target=freddy)  # gab follows freddy
```

In the GetStream dashboard for feed `user:freddy.id` I see that there are 2 followers `timeline_aggregated:gab.id` and `timeline:gab.id`.

Now, If I load freddy's timeline_aggregated:

```
feed_manager.get_feed('timeline_aggregated', freddy.id)
activities = self.feed.get(limit=self.page_size)['results']
```

It doesn't contain the reference that "gab follows freddy", hence `activities` is `{}`, instead I expected to have that in.

Am I wrong?

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Follow model is saved an activity is created and added to the user feed of the follower and a copy is sent to the notification feed of the target (see `Follow.activity_notify`).

From your example, the activity "gab follows freddy" should be in these two feeds: "user:bag" and "notification:freddy".